# Are Observables extension of Promises

Tags: angular

I know the difference between these two and the intent of this question is not to know them.

I have been asked this twice and I really cannot find any online articles explaining it.

Are `observables` written by extending `promises` or both of them have a totally different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually different though looking quite similar.

You can look at an Observable implementation [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts) and [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts) is a subscription.

I don't see any trace of Promise usage in base of Observables. They are just objects which have many useful methods.